# Unable to access constructor's value from a prototype in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, constructor, prototype

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0jpt7tkk/1/)

**Question:**  Why is `this.decks.push(data);` coming up undefined?  How can I get `deckCtrl.decks` to properly log out?

Error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

```
var DECK_DATA = {};
DECK_DATA.cards = [
    {
        faces: [
            {
                name: 'a',
                src: '',
                link: ''
            },
            {
                name: 'b',
                src: '',
                link: ''
            },
            {
                name: 'b',
                src: '',
                link: ''
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        faces: [
            {
                name: 'a',
                src: '',
                link: ''
            },
            {
                name: 'b',
                src: '',
                link: ''
            },
            {
                name: 'b',
                src: '',
                link: ''
            }
        ]
    }
];
//Classes
var Deck = (function () {
    function Deck(card) {
        this.cards = card;
    }
    return Deck;
})();
var DeckController = (function () {
    function DeckController() {
        this.decks = [];
    }
    DeckController.prototype.addDeck = function (data) {
        console.log(data, this.decks); //this.decks comes up undefined.
        this.decks.push(data);
    };
    return DeckController;
})();
//main
var deckBuilder = Deck;
var deckCtrl = DeckController;
DECK_DATA.cards.forEach(function (item) {
    deckCtrl.prototype.addDeck(new deckBuilder(item));
});
console.log(deckCtrl.decks);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `new` to create a new instance:

```
var deckBuilder = new Deck();
var deckCtrl = new DeckController();
```

And you want to use the addDeck of the instance, not of the prototype:

```
DECK_DATA.cards.forEach(function (item) {
    deckCtrl.addDeck(new deckBuilder(item));
});
```